# two different mint functions, one nft collection, one contract

Tags: solidity, nft

mintApe() and mintPunk() and the apes functions gives you tokenid < 5000 for example, and punk > 4999

Any problems with that ?

Comment: What do you mean? What are `mintApe`, `mintPunk`? What do you mean by `punk > 4999`?

Comment: token id, instead of one mint() - like the erc721 std

Comment: If they are functions in your contract then you can do anything you want. In the ERC-721 standard any uint256 is a valid tokenId. You could use consecutive numbers from 0, start at 1000, even numbers, odd numbers, random numbers, etc.